# Is there a site for tracking driving licence's requirements across an itinerary?

Tags: driving-licenses, eastern-europe, southeast-europe

At the end of October I'm planning to drive my motorbike from Milano to my new temporary home in Kalamata, and In doing so I'd love to drive across a few country I've not yet pinned from my list, but:

1. Generally speaking, I'm not sure if there are exceptions even in the EU in regard to driving licences
2. I'd love to be able to change direction whenever I feel like it, so I'd be better to check every single country from Adriatic sea to Russian Borders, but it's a huge list.

I checked on Google but my usual Google-fu is failing me this time, so I'm asking here: is there some site I can put an itinerary into and get a list of all permits I need, or even better some infographic showing that info for the aforementioned countries?

Comment: I think basic license reciprocity is fairly universal. Do you have reason to believe it isn't?

Comment: No, but I have no reasons to believe the opposite too :-)

Comment: Fair enough. I already upvoted. If I were you, though, I'd be more worried about my insurance. Have you asked your insurer?

Comment: Not yet, I'm changing motorbike in the next days so I'll have to move the insurance from one to the other and I'll ask in that moment. But then...thanks for pointing it out, 'cause if you didn't do it, I'd never had realized that I should have asked :-DDD I owe you a couple of beers :D

Comment: All EU/EEA countries recognize each other's licenses, it's one of the basic laws of the union.

Comment: I  don't think I completely understand your question.  I thought driver's licenses issued in EU where valid in the whole EU.  I just checked this: http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/vehicles/driving-licence/driving-licence-recognition-validity/index_en.htm.

Comment: @KrisCaluwaerts I think you have an answer there.

Answer (score 1):

All european countries (EU) share the same driving license, and there's a lot (Turkey, all currently applying countries, UK) of non--eu or non-schengen zones that share the same system and thus "convalidate" your license.

As long as you've got one of these types , you'll be fine. and when it gets old, you'll have to renew it at your new homeplace.

When outside of europe you might need the IDP to keep driving with your license.

It's a document that accompanies you license.

Countries that recognize the IDP:

[image]

dark blue : 100% valid.  light blue : 100% too, but might need extra paperwork.

more info:

[International Driving Permit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Driving_Permit)

[image]

Comment: If you have an EU license, you don't even need an IDP within the EU.

Comment: EU liscenses count as IDP as far as i know.

Comment: NO, they don't. An IDP is a translation of an existing license, that has no validity without an accompanying license. An EU driving license is just an EU driving License.

Comment: you learn something new everyday.

Comment: This answer is a bit inaccurate. EU countries issue their own licences and recognise all other EU licences. The IDP is not the EU license system, it's not even a license but a supplementary document that many countries recognize and a few require for international visitors. However it's not required at all for EU country license holders travelling in other EU countries.

Comment: edited to clarificate

Comment: Still quite a few inaccuracies. This is a question that calls for precision. Sorry would edit, but I'm on mobile.